# the use of operator >> or << in solidity

Tags: solidity, operator

```
    CountersUpgradeable.Counter private nonce;

    function mintERC721() ... {
        uint256 tokenId;
        unchecked {
            tokenId = (nonce << 128);
        }
        ...
        nonce.increment();
    }
```

What does `(nonce << 128)` do? seems like it's creating a very large number. Is it a random number within 128 bit that will never collide when nonce increases every time? Why would this be better than a sequential tokenId increase? i.e. 1,2,3,4, etc

```
function tokenToNonce(uint256 _tokenId) ... {
    uint256 nonce = _tokenId >> 128;
    if (nonce == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    return nonce;
}
```

This one is interesting too, operator now switched to the other way around `>>`

My understanding is it can find a `nonce` based on `tokenId` or 0 if `tokenId` was not created before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's Bitwise Operations, left shift `<<` and right shift `>>`. Ideal to manipulate binary bits directly and efficiently.

Learn more about bitwise operations here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_bitwise.asp
It's a Javascript resource, but bitwise operations behave exactly the same in all the languages that support them.

What the code is doing is left shifting the `nonce` 128 bits.

Let's use smaller numbers to see it easier.

Let's suppose `nonce` is 5. Its binary representation is `101`. Now, let's left shift it by 1:

```
tokenId = 5 << 1;
```

Now, we assigned `5 << 1` tokenId. Its binary representation will be `1010`. Notice how the `101` just got moved 1 position to the left. Its decimal value is now 10. You can convert it here: https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/binary-to-decimal.html?x=1010

If we left shift 5 by 2: `5 << 2`, we get a binary representation like `10100`. If we convert it to decimal, we get 20. On each left shift, we basically double the value due to the binary representation.

The right shift operator `>>` is doing the opposite, shifting the number to the right. If we have `20 >> 2` we get `101`, 5, where we started.

As for the reason that code is doing that, I'm not sure, I guess they would have their logical reasons.

I wrote this article about binary representation, it can help you. It does not contain bitwise operations, but helps in understanding binary numbers: https://medium.com/coinsbench/signed-vs-unsigned-integers-binary-representation-overflows-pitfalls-109bc1ef6ef0